# React event handler

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In this React event handling code, is there any semicolon missing? Because when I run it shows missing semicolon in line X:

```
changemessage () {
  this.setState({ message: " Thanks for sub" })
}
```

Comment: Do you have a linter doing code checks for you? ESlint for example can be configured to require a semicolon at the end of a statement and your `this.setState()` doesn't end with one.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want:

```
function changemessage() {
  this.setState({ message: " Thanks for sub" })
}
```

Or:

```
changemessage = () => {
  this.setState({ message: " Thanks for sub" })
}
```

Because the way you wrote it is incorrect (assuming this is not part of a class-based component), it might be expecting a semicolon here, thinking you were trying to invoke `changemessage`, but that's not the case:

```
changemessage (); { this.setState({ message: " Thanks for sub" }) }
```

Comment: When I tried it shows changemessage is not defined.

Comment: And when I used 1st solution calling changemessage as a function then it shows it is not function. By the way above code is in constructor.

Comment: @1morestuff The last example is not a solution, it's just part of the explanation. Can you update your question to include all the code and not just this method?